# Change SublimeText2 config paths

Tags: sublimetext2

Is it possible to change the path where SublimeText 2 loads your user snippets from?

I'd like to use Dropbox to synchronise them across multiple systems, and don't want to configure an additional "sync" tool on each machine.

There doesn't appear to be anything in the user configuration or documentation for changing the path, so I'm not holding my breath.